# Third-party or third party?

Tags: american-english, british-english, dashes

Does British English use a dash in between third-party, or is that for American English?

Comment: No one uses a dash. Perhaps you are thinking of a hyphen.

Comment: Apologies. I meant a hyphen.

Comment: You can edit your post and replace *dash* with *hyphen*. Users on EL&U are sticklers for precision, but it's true the correct punctuation term is the one suggested by @tchrist.

Answer (score 3):

I think there may be a certain propensity for using the hyphenated form as an adjective, but not as a noun.